# React-Native FlatList RenderItem Testing With Jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, code-coverage, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

I have developed Component `UserContainer` which uses FlatList I am able to test the FlatList test using Jest.

`Note` I am not using Enzyme library for testing

But don't know how to test `renderItem={renderItem}`

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
<View>
  <UserCard title={item.login} image={item.avatar_url} />
</View>
);

<FlatList
  data={usersState.users.data}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
/>
```

Anyone, please help

Comment: Any update on this issue??